# Rails is rendering partial view, when it should only be updating the partial view in an existing page

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I'm trying to implement up/down-voting a post through AJAX, so that users don't have to refresh the page to see the updated score. However, when the voting links are clicked, the user is redirected to a page that only displays the partial view. The parent view is not even displayed. How can I update the partial in the index page without refreshing the entire page? I suspect that the problem lies in my 'vote' controller action. Here is my code so far:

## /app/controllers/posts_controllers.rb

```
def vote
  value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
  respond_to do |format|
    #I'm guessing the problem lies here.
    format.html { render partial: 'score', locals: {post: @post} }
    format.js
  end
end
```

## /app/views/posts/_score.html.erb

```
<td id="score_<%= post.id %>"><%= post.reputation_for(:votes).to_i %></td>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<td>
  <%= button_to "Upvote", vote_post_path(post, type: "up"), method: "post", class: "btn btn-success", remote: true %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= button_to "Downvote", vote_post_path(post, type: "down"), method: "post", class: "btn btn-danger", remote: true %>
</td>
<% end %>
```

## /app/views/posts/score.js.erb

```
$('#score_<%= post.id %>').html("<%= escape_javaScript render partial: 'score', locals: {post: @post} %>");
```

## /app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render partial: 'score', locals: {post: post} %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

## /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Im guessing its not passing through the javascript and the link is just a normal anchor.

Comment: The "link" is a Rails `button_to`. Note that I added the `remote: true` attribute to the button. Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

The `js` branch of your response misses the block that states which view should be rendered:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render partial: 'score', locals: {post: @post} }
  format.js { render partial: 'score', locals: {post: @post} }
end
```

Otherwise the rails default would be to render `vote.js`, since this is your controller method name. And maybe it's just a typo but your file should be named `_score.js.erb` (partial), just like the HTML version.

**UPDATE**

Having reviewed your code once more, maybe it's enough to simply rename `score.js.erb` to `vote.js.erb`, since you render the `_score` partial in there.

And from a design point of view, the cleanest and driest solution would be to skip the blocks for the `format` calls and have the files like so:

```
# posts_controllers.rb
def vote
  value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # this renders vote.html.erb
    format.js    # this renders vote.js.erb
  end
end


# vote.html.erb
<%= render 'score', locals: { post: @post } %>


# vote.js.erb
$('#score_<%= @post.id %>').html("<%= escape_javaScript render partial: 'score', locals: { post: @post } %>");


# _score.html.haml
<td id="score_<%= post.id %>"><%= post.reputation_for(:votes).to_i %></td>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<td>
  <%= button_to "Upvote", vote_post_path(post, type: "up"), method: "post", class: "btn btn-success", remote: true %>
</td>
<td>
  <%= button_to "Downvote", vote_post_path(post, type: "down"), method: "post", class: "btn btn-danger", remote: true %>
</td>


# index.html.erb
<%= render 'score', collection: @posts, as: :post %>
```

Comment: I made the changes you indicated in the update in your posts. However, navigating to /posts results in [undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x49bbfe8>:0x4760bb0>](http://i.imgur.com/OpPadrK.png?1).

Comment: Also, I instead tried reversing those changes and only doing the changes you suggested before your edit. Again, only the partial view shows up in the browser.